# undefined of something that is clearly defined

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2

this must be some JavaScript concept that I am not grasping yet..

For some odd reason the **id** of **thisSound** returns undefined! why??

```
console.log("o: "+o.id+" - "+decodeURI(soundURL));
// create sound
thisSound = soundManager.createSound({
    id:o.id,
    url:decodeURI(soundURL)
});

console.log("thisSound: "+thisSound.id+" - "+thisSound.url);
```

the console :

```
o: Sound0 - http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/76673175/stream?client_id=e992d357c0914e9b65ba17f459720fc0

thisSound: undefined - http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/76673175/stream?client_id=e992d357c0914e9c65ba17f459720fc0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided doesn't “obviously” define the `id` of the returned object.

```
// create sound
thisSound = soundManager.createSound({
    id:o.id,
    url:decodeURI(soundURL)
});
```

Let's say I write the function `createSound` for you:

```
var soundManager = {
  createSound: function (options) {
    // do internal magic here
    createSound(options);
    // return public API here
    return {
      getId: function () {}
    }
  }
};
```

So, my point here is that if there is a third-party function, you should follow the docs of whoever created that function, and SoundManager apparently doesn't return an object with `id` property defined on it. It “[returns a SMSound object instance](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/)” – and what is that object, please find out in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about the soundcloud library, although the function `createSound`seems asyncronous... (It's like I/O Stuff, the most of the I/O operations in javascript -and the other languages- are async ).. Is it possible when you have called the `console.log` thisSound hasn't been fully created yet? Maybe you could emulate a `setInterval()` behaviour with a lot of time and this code works... (although I believe you should use a callback function for this).